# How to speed up VBA nested if

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have a nested if statement that is slow.

I have some bad dates in a spreadsheet. I am trying to make a new column to correct the invalid data.
Depending on what is in there, I put a date from either column J or K.
If the data is good, I keep what is in column I.

```vb
For i = 2 To TempLastRow
    If IsDate(.Cells(i, "I").Value) = False _
      Then .Cells(i, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "K").Value _
      Else If DateValue(Format(.Cells(i, "I").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")) < DateValue("01/01/2013") _
      Then .Cells(i, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "K").Value _
      Else .Cells(i, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value
Next i
```

I have this at the top of my macro:

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Comment: It'd be better to read the data into an array and loop the array instead of looping cell-by-cell.

Comment: Also, consider using the multi-line form of `If` instead of the line continuations you're using.

Comment: You could also make your code add a column, and then add an excel formula to that column that does something similar to your code. This would be faster than looping through cell by cell in vba

Comment: ... and why do you think your performance drop is caused by the nested if-loop? Normally those things are quite fast. I believe your performance drop is caused by something else.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the range to an array, modifying the values and copying the array back will probably be 10x faster.
But if you want to stick to your solution,
a) move calls out of the loop if the result is constant, and
b) do not reference the cell more than once by `Cells()`

So:

```
Dim i_value, k_value
Dim oldest_date As Date

oldest_date = DateSerial(2013, 1, 1)

For i = 2 To TempLastRow
    i_value = .Cells(i, "I").Value
    k_value = .Cells(i, "K").Value
    
    If Not IsDate(i_value) Then
        .Cells(i, "J").Value = k_value
    ElseIf i_value < oldest_date Then
        .Cells(i, "J").Value = k_value
    Else
        .Cells(i, "J").Value = i_value
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `if...ElseIf` statement and avoiding `DateValue` which is consuming.

```vb
For i = 2 To TempLastRow
    If Not IsDate(.Cells(i, "I").Value) Then
        .Cells(i, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "K").Value
    ElseIf .Cells(i, "I").Value < DateSerial(2013, 1, 1) Then
        .Cells(i, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "K").Value
    Else
        .Cells(i, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value
    End If
Next i
```